# Is it possible to share Images in twitter using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, api, twitter

Let me clarify first. I tried the API to **Upload Picture** to twitter, But it uses consumer key and user token to select an account and uploads images using before said single account only.

So, if there are multiple users, like in a social networking site, It is not possible to use that way I think. Because, at there, there are multiple users and each need to share images from their individual accounts. Unfortunately, still, I havent seen such a way to share images in twitter!

So, Is there any other method to share image in twitter as we do facebook/pinterest share of images in our websites?

Comment: Have you tried retweeting the original image - or simply sharing the URL of an image?

Comment: I tried sharing image url... Its not working... re tweeting is not an option I have...

Comment: How is it not working? What error are you getting? Millions of people share image URLs on Twitter every day.

Comment: I can share image url.. But It appear only as a url. Instead I need it to show photo on my post. Like we share image in twitter.

Comment: Then you need to share the URL of a previously uploaded Twitter image. Sharing pic.twitter.com/bCfLMEKS1d will show an image in the post.